# Is there a way for me to start crond (daemon, not job) programmatically at a specific time?

Tags: bash, cron, daemon

I am trying to run the command `sudo service crond start` starting 11:59AM everday programmatically in an Amazon AWS EC2 instance shell that is always up and running. In the `crontab`, I have a `cron job` that triggers a shell script every 15 minutes from noon to midnight (i.e. `*/15 12-23 * * * /path/to/script`).

This script checks an Amazon AWS S3 bucket for some file and runs the jar when found. Then it stops the crond by running command `sudo service crond stop` after successfully executing the jar file.

It would work fine if I never run `sudo service crond stop` but I am curious.

Is there a way for me to achieve this without using another `crontab`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're trying to schedule a task scheduler to run without using the task scheduler... you need to use one other scheduler, which needs to have its daemon ran at startup.

Try looking at:
anacron
at

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.